# преобразовать Color в Drawable

Tags: android, view, color, android-drawable

Как можно преобразовать `Color` в `Drawable`, чтобы программно указать `background` для `view` ? метода `setColorBackground()` нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ нашел, словно под заказ есть прекрасный объект ColorDrawable который получает цвет из xml и работает как полноценный Drawable

Answer (score 1):

У view есть метод `setBackgroungColor();`

Как пример : `setBackgroungColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));`

Или с ресурсов :

`setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorWhite));`

```
setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_draw));
```

Comment: Я же написал, что его нет, ну точнее не то чтобы его нет, а он не рабочий. Нужно конкретно указать Color в качестве Drawable

Comment: @PashaDoncov этот метод работает нормально для `view`, если у вас специфичный или кастомный компонент - укажите его

Comment: Возможно вам нужно что-то типа этого? view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.black));

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii да

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю что вот такой код (на Kotlin):

```
color1 = resources.getDrawable(R.color.color1)
```

будучи запущенным в блоке инициализации - выдает NullPointerException. Если запускать его в onCreate (или позже) - то все нормально работает